# Входные данные для сверточной нейронной сети

Tags: python, алгоритм, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, машинное-зрение

Не могу разобраться с преобразованием изображений на вход сверточной сети. Например я хочу распознать окружности на фотографии 1000х1000 pxs. Сеть обучается на данных 100х100 pxs. Не могу в голове уложить одну ситуацию, когда окружность на входном рисунке гораздо больше(или меньше) 100х100 pxs, как в таком случае сверточная сеть определяет ту окружность, если она была научена на данных другого размера. Много искал в сети, но в голове путаница.
Для наглядности на вход сети хочу подавать изображение 454х430 pxs:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сеть обучается на данных 100х100 pxs:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе хочу распознать все окружности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рисунки приблизительные.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо сжать фотография до 100x100 px(Если вектор увеличился система не примет его)